# How to throw error and exit with a custom message in python

Tags: python, error-handling

I've seen people suggesting sys.exit() in Python.
My question is that, is there any other way to exit the execution of current script, I mean termination, with an error.

Something like this:

```
sys.exit("You can not have three process at the same time.")
```

Currently my solution would be:

```
print("You can not have three process at the same time.")
sys.exit()
```

Comment: http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html perhaps

Answer (score 161, accepted):

Calling `sys.exit` with a string will work. The [docs](http://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.exit) mention this use explicitly:

> In particular, sys.exit("some error message") is a quick way to exit a program when an error occurs.

Comment: Just higligting one important point of using sys.exit("some error message") from the python documentaion.
If another type of object is passed, None is equivalent to passing zero, and any other object is printed to stderr and results in an exit code of 1

Answer (score 66):

There are 3 approaches, the first as lvc mentioned is using sys.exit

```
sys.exit('My error message')
```

The second way is using `print`, print can write almost anything including an error message

```
print >>sys.stderr, "fatal error"     # Python 2.x
print("fatal error", file=sys.stderr) # Python 3.x
```

The third way is to rise an exception which I don't like because it can be `try-catch`

```
  raise SystemExit('error in code want to exit')
```

it can be ignored like this

```
try:
  raise SystemExit('error in code want to exit')
except:
  print("program is still open")
```

Comment: Just an FYI, `sys.exit()` raises a `SystemExit` exception. Hence it can also be caught in a try-except block.

Comment: @hr87 I said it if you read carefully

Comment: @nimamoradi actually you should be the one reading carefully... hr87 is saying that sys.exit() also raises an exception under the hood, making your third point (not liking raise SystemExit because it can be try-catched) moot.

Answer (score 27):

You can also raise an error like this:

```
raise SystemExit('Error: 3 processes cannot run simultaneously.')
```

One advantage of this approach is that you don't have to import the Python `sys` module. This works on Linux with Python 3 and Python 2. I have not tested it on Windows or Mac OS.

Comment: Works for me on macos w pyenv 2 & 3

Comment: Works on Windows 10

Answer (score 7):

You have to use `import sys` first

Then use `sys.exit("your custom error message")`

Answer (score 0):

There's also a convenience function called `exit()` in Python, no need to import anything for this.

Here's a simple example:

```bash
$ python3 -c "exit('This should work...')" ; echo "exit code: $?"
This should work...
exit code: 1
```

Comment: I get name 'exit' is not defined (Python 3.11)

Comment: @rhody I'm sorry to hear that, and not sure why. 

I've just tried to run the snippet in a terminal on a fresh install of Ubuntu 22.04 using Python 3.10.12, on my main Ubuntu 22.04 box using Python 3.11.7 & Python 3.10.12, also on macOS (M1) using Python 3.11.5 & Python 3.10.13; it worked in each case. 

From a quick Google search, I found there's no simple answer to why this happens to some. I figured it's safer to use either `import sys; sys.exit()` or `raise SystemExit()`.