# How to get an exit code in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, exception, exit

I am studying about exceptions and exit codes for errors but my terminal does not give me an exit code in Python 3.8 on Windows 10.

I would like to be able to se the message *"Process finished with exit code 0"* from a simple *"hello world"* program for example.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html?#sys.exit - which part are you having trouble with? Welcome to SO. This isn't a discussion forum or tutorial. Please take the [tour] and take the time to read [ask] and the other links found on that page.

Comment: Related: [Exit codes in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/285289/exit-codes-in-python), [How to terminate a Python script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73663/how-to-terminate-a-python-script), [How to throw error and exit with a custom message in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22633544/how-to-throw-error-and-exit-with-a-custom-message-in-python).  Many more searching with `python exit code message site:stackoverflow.com` - do any of them fit your needs? If so choose one and vote to close your question as a duplicate.

Comment: "Process finished with exit code whatever" is a message printed by PyCharm. Displaying exit codes is not your Python program's responsibility - after all, to *have* an exit code, your program must have already exited. (You can't print *before* exiting, because something might catch `SystemExit` or do something else that changes how the exit happens.)

Comment: You need to check the exit code from outside the program. How to do that depends on how you're running it - for example, in a Windows command prompt, you might use [`%errorlevel%`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/334879/how-do-i-get-the-application-exit-code-from-a-windows-command-line)

Comment: I think Monica might have found what I needed, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Enjoy this Full Explanation demo.

```
import subprocess


result = subprocess.run("C:/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0/powershell.exe Write-Output 'Hello world!' ", shell=True, capture_output=True) # command to run in powershell using python subprocess module

res = result.returncode # return system-exit code of the command

out = result.stdout # return output of the powershell command


print(f"The output of the command is {out}, The exit code is {res} and the process generated by command is {result}.")
```

output

```
The output of the command is b'Hello world!\r\n', The exit code is 0 and the process generated by command is CompletedProcess(args="C:/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0/powershell.exe Write-Output 'Hello world!' ", returncode=0, stdout=b'Hello world!\r\n', stderr=b'').
```

Answer (score 0):

**EDITED ANSWER** :
There must be some unhandled exceptions/errors in your exercise, so that it didn't exit with **exit code 0** (which means successful execution of your exercise). Add Try at the start of your program and catching the exception at the end as below sample program.

**print() function always returns None, so don't try getting return status from print()**

```
import sys

try:
    print('hello world')                      #print('string') - Always returns None
    print("Process finished with exit code 0")
    sys.exit(0)
except Exception as ex:
    print("Error:"+ex)
    sys.exit(1)
```

Comment: This is not exactly what I am looking for, my question maybe more related to how different terminals handle the python programs (pycharm, cmd, powershell). I am folowing a class and the exercise has no "print("Process finished with exit code 0")" line, it just appears on the terminal at the end.

Comment: when The Process finished with **exit code 0** it means that the process is successful, else there is an issue such as **exit code 1 or more**. I suggest to learn python **subprocess** module or in general **Interacting with OS using Python**

Comment: @FredhRodrigues
The line "Processs finished with exit code 0" appears at the END because, there was no runtime exception caught while running the exercise. (**exit code 0** indicates successful running of your exercise ) whereas exit code **other than 0** may denote some  specific errors/exceptions caught in the exercise